# Process of finding relative extrema

Tags: calculus

Question 1

Khan Academy outlines that possible relative extrema points can be found by seeing 1) where the original function is undefined 2) where the derivative is undefined but defined for the original function and 3) where the derivative is equal to zero and defined for the original function. 2) and 3) make sense, but how does 1)? A relative extrema has to be defined for the original function obviously.

Question 2

Assuming that 1) actually makes sense and that I just don't understand at the moment, if I have the equation $\ln (x)$, the domain is undefined for all $x\leq0$, so an infinite number of points could be possible candidates for a relative extrema?

Comment: You are correct that a relative extremum can only occur at a point where the original function is defined.  Hence, if the function $f: (0, \infty) \to \mathbb{R}$ defined by $f(x) = \ln x$ had any relative extrema (it does not since it is monotonically increasing), they would have to occur in the positive real numbers.

Comment: @N.F.Taussig then why does Khan Academy say that a point which is undefined for the original function can be candidate for a relative extrema?

Comment: @N.F.Taussig Here is the website https://www.khanacademy.org/math/ap-calculus-ab/ab-diff-analytical-applications-new/ab-5-4/a/applying-the-first-derivative-test-to-find-extrema     You can look at step 2.

Comment: Under the heading "In our case", the third point states "$f$ is undefined at $x = 1$, so it does not have an extremum point there."  The reason why we are interested in points where the function is undefined is that the sign of the derivative can change sign there, so the function may change from increasing to decreasing or vice versa at an asymptote.

Comment: @N.F. Taussig Oh so we test undefined points in the first derivative test because if we do not then we might erroneously determine that a critical point is not a relative extrema when in fact it is?

Comment: That is correct.